# how to jump from GP to Quick-books?

Tags: sql, asp.net, quickbooks

I am developer on e-commerce website (built in asp.net & sql), right now we are using GP to create order, invoice etc...

We want to use quickbooks instead of GP, so we want to integrate our website with quickbooks, i do not know what i should do?

What specific technologies should I use to do the integration part?

Should I use Windows service, web Service..?

Comment: I am Developing an appliction that store data to SQL Server databas as well as QucikBooks Database.. and i have the same question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to read about QuickBooks SDK 13.0 Installer
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb/0020_get_set_up/sdk_downloads